# Drop down menu: remove overlap between text and customised arrow in Chrome

Tags: html, css

I'd like to remove the overlap between the arrow and text in Chrome if possible.

**This is what happens in different browsers:**

[image: Dropdown Example]

**This is the code:**

```css
.search-options-wrapper select {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    -moz-appearance: none;
    background: url("http://i60.tinypic.com/w888ic.png") no-repeat 88px center;
    background-size: 12px; 
    overflow:hidden;
    display: flex;
    border: 0; 
}
```

```html
<div class="search-options-wrapper"> 
    <select id="options-primary">
        <option>short text</option>
        <option>Long text lalalalalaa</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What I would do is add `padding-right` that will contain your background image of the down arrow. Then change it's placement so it is not starting 88px from the left of the select box. This way the text doesn't have an opportunity to run into your arrow as it cannot enter the padded area.

```css
.search-options-wrapper select {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    -moz-appearance: none;
    background: url("http://i60.tinypic.com/w888ic.png") no-repeat right center;
    background-size: 12px;
    padding-right: 20px;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: flex;
    border: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="search-options-wrapper">
    <select id="options-primary">
        <option>short text</option>
        <option>Long text lalalalalaa</option>
    </select>
</div>
```